# Set option in <mat- select > based on index of option programmatically

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have  whose options are prefilled with a service.
The Options have same 'value' but 'Description' is different

For example :

`list=[ {value:1, Description:'a'}, {value:1, Description:'b'}, {value:1, Description:'c'}]`

I am capturing the value and description separately in storing in backend DB.
Now,

1. While reloading I want to map to the option which user has selected (lets say 'b')
2. but when I use

   `this.fgHeaderForm.patchValue({ selectformCtrName:"1" })`

this shows the very 1st option as selected in the  (that will be 'a' in our case)
3. I want to show second option that is 'b' as selected
4. I have tried setting the

`document.getElementById("sel").textContent='b'`

but this cause select to lost its drop down functionality and user then can not change if wish to do so.

What can be done so that I can set the index in  for example in above case
'b' is at index =1 so option 'b' will be set in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understand your question, you have an array and want to use the indexes as the value in the
`<mat-option>` ?

In that case you can do it like this:

```
<mat-select formControlName="selectformCtrName" >
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of list; let i = index" [value]="i">
    {{option.Description}}
 </mat-option>  
</mat-select>
```

Then you can set the values of the form with the index of the array.

```
this.fgHeaderForm.patchValue({selectedformCtrName: "1"});
```

The drawback will be, that in order to get the selected Description or Value you need to retrieve the selected index from the FormGroup again.

Comment: Thanks  Havald for your answer. I used the solution, modified it a bit as per required. Now I get index of selected option from that I fetch Value. Great Help !